# Validate field in observablearray not working (using knockout validation plugin)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

I am using the knockout validation plug in and am trying to compare a date field in the observablearray to a static date.  I know the code is not complete, but here is what i have-

EDIT: VIEW CODE-

```
                                         <tbody data-bind="foreach: allCertificates">
                                        <tr id="AllCertRow" style="cursor: pointer" data-bind="click: $parent.selectThing, css: { highlight: $parent.isSelected() == $data.lwCertID }">
                                            <td>
                                                <ul >

                                                   <li><H5><b><span data-bind="    text: clientName"></span>&nbsp;(<span data-bind="    text: clientNumber"></span>)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span data-bind="    text: borrowBaseCount"></span>&nbsp;Loan(s)&nbsp;</b></H5></li>
                                                    Collateral Analyst:&nbsp;<span data-bind="    text: userName"></span>
                                                    <br />
                                                Certificate:&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: lwCertID"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Request&nbsp;Date:&nbsp;<span data-bind="    text: moment(requestDate).format('DD/MMM/YYYY')"></span>
                                                    </ul>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
```

My viewmodel code-

```
         var LucasSystemDate = ko.observableArray('4/22/2013');
     var allCertificates = ko.observableArray([]);

        ko.validation.configure({
        registerExtenders: true,
        messagesOnModified: true,
        insertMessages: true,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        messageTemplate: null,
        grouping: {
            deep: true
        }
    });

        ko.validation.rules['Expired'] = {
        validator: function (val, otherVal) {
            return val < otherVal;
        },
        message: 'Request has expired. Please reject and initiate client contact.'
    };

    var activate = function () {
        // go get local data, if we have it
        return true;
    };


    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        LucasSystemDate: LucasSystemDate,
    allCertificates: allCertificates[
        { lwCertID: '2', clientID: '1EX', requestDate: '7/3/2013 12:34:00 PM', userName: 'Peter Rabbit', statusDescription:     'Submitted', statusCode: '1', statusDesc: 'Submitted', clientName: 'Test Company 1                     ', clientNumber: '1EX',  borrowBaseCount: '1', advRequestCount: '1', ceoUserName: 'Woodall, Chris' },
{ lwCertID: '5', clientID: '1EX  ', requestDate: '7/3/2013 1:00:00 PM', userName: 'Bugs Bunny', statusDescription: 'Submitted',     statusCode: '1', statusDesc: 'Submitted', clientName: 'Test Company 2                     ', clientNumber: '1EX',   borrowBaseCount: '1', advRequestCount: '1', ceoUserName: 'Woodall, Chris' },
{ lwCertID: '6', clientID: '1EX  ', requestDate: '7/8/2013 6:31:00 AM', userName: 'Jack Frost', statusDescription: 'Submitted',     statusCode: '1', statusDesc: 'Submitted', clientName: 'Test Company 3                     ', clientNumber: '1EX',   borrowBaseCount: '1', advRequestCount: '1', ceoUserName: 'Woodall, Chris' }
    ]
}

//NOT SURE HOW TO COMPARE requestDate IN THE allCertificates OBSERVEABLEARRAY TO 
//THE LucasSystemDate.  IF LucasSystemDate < allCertificates.requestDate
//THEN FAIL VALIDATION AND DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE.  THIS CHECK SHOULD 
//BE PERFORMED EACH TIME THE DATA IS INITIALLY LOADED.
```

Under the commented out code at the bottom of the code above, what code would I put here to use the Expired validation rule to compare the requestDate in the allCertificates observablearray to the LucasSystemDate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that our date is not an array, it is simply a date value, so fix that and you should be able to compare it to anything you want -

```
var LucasSystemDate = ko.observableArray('4/22/2013');
```

should be

```
var LucasSystemDate = ko.observable('4/22/2013');
```

This should be an example of how to create a rule and then apply it to something, but I can't be 100% sure this will compile and run like you want.  You may need to tweak it.

```
// Create a new rule called expired
ko.validation.rules['expired'] = {
    validator: function (val, otherVal) {
        // val appears to be the value of the observable, otherVal appears to be the value you set the rule equal to
        return val < otherVal;
    },
    message: 'Request has expired. Please reject and initiate client contact.'
};
// It looks like you need to register these extensions
ko.validation.registerExtenders();

// No sense in making the date either observable nor an observable array, as you won't be using it in the DOM
var LucasSystemDate = new Date('4/22/2013');

var allCertificates = ko.observableArray();

// This doesn't need to be observable but to save time I made it an observable array so I could use the arrayForEach util
var certsArray = ko.observableArray([
{ lwCertID: '2', clientID: '1EX', requestDate: '7/3/2013 12:34:00 PM', userName: 'Peter Rabbit', statusDescription:     'Submitted', statusCode: '1', statusDesc: 'Submitted', clientName: 'Test Company 1                     ', clientNumber: '1EX',  borrowBaseCount: '1', advRequestCount: '1', ceoUserName: 'Woodall, Chris' },
{ lwCertID: '5', clientID: '1EX  ', requestDate: '7/3/2013 1:00:00 PM', userName: 'Bugs Bunny', statusDescription: 'Submitted',     statusCode: '1', statusDesc: 'Submitted', clientName: 'Test Company 2                     ', clientNumber: '1EX',   borrowBaseCount: '1', advRequestCount: '1', ceoUserName: 'Woodall, Chris' },
{ lwCertID: '6', clientID: '1EX  ', requestDate: '7/8/2013 6:31:00 AM', userName: 'Jack Frost', statusDescription: 'Submitted',     statusCode: '1', statusDesc: 'Submitted', clientName: 'Test Company 3                     ', clientNumber: '1EX',   borrowBaseCount: '1', advRequestCount: '1', ceoUserName: 'Woodall, Chris' }]);

// Iterate through the array, extend with the validator, and push the cert into the all certs observable array
ko.utils.arrayForEach(certsArray(), function (cert) {
    cert.extend({ expired: LucasSystemDate });
    allCertificates.push(cert);
});

// Expose the functions / observables to the DOM
var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    LucasSystemDate: LucasSystemDate,
    allCertificates: allCertificates
};

// Apply your bindings, you may not need to do this if you are using a framework which binds for you
ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Comment: Thanks PW. I am new to knockout validation.  Can you give me a little more?  Perhaps a bare bones example.  Not sure where your ko.utils.arrayForEach statement would go.  The reject logic would simply be printing 'Request has expired' in the list within the view (I added view code to my post). What would that look like?

Comment: The concept of Knockout validation can be seen at this link - https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation - but basically you are extending the observable.  I would highly suggest that you make the adjustments I mentioned above and study the link as you will understand how to use knockout validation and won't have to come back here to ask for more help next time you are using it : )

Comment: I studied that.  That is where I got the ko.validation.rules in my code from.  What is does not give me is the details. How all of this fits together.

Comment: It shows me a custom rule, but what do I do with that?  It is like being asked to cook a particular dish and given only sugar.  Have no idea what the other ingredients are, so I have no idea what the dish I am being asked to make.

Comment: Look at the getting started section.  When you create an observable you extend it with validation properties.  It's fairly simple, I will throw a bit of additional logic in my answer.

Comment: Alright I added a sample, based off their website, that MAY do what you are looking for or may need some tweaking.  If you don't understand what observables are or what arrays are then you probably need to do some more studying before using the technology though because it is very important to understand what you are doing.